# Cyclic calling of event receivers

Tags: development, event-receivers

I have a Deleting Event Receiver, say, on list A. Also I have other Deleting Event Receiver on list B. There is a deleting method in both receivers, which deletes items of each other. So, when an item is being deleted in list A the event receiver on list B also rises to delete item in list A. Cyclic calling of event receivers appears.

How can I escape of this situation? I need delete items from list A and list B wherever Event Receiver is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [EventFiringEnabled](http://SPEventReceiverBase.EventFiringEnabled) to false before calling Delete and reset it to true afterwards. This will prevent Events from firing in the current task due to the Delete

Answer (score 1):

Add a column called "IsDeleted", which each event receiver sets on the item before it deletes it.

Then add a check on each event receiver to make sure the field isn't marked "IsDeleted"

Comment: Thank's for answer, but I think, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028834/cyclic-calling-of-event-receivers) decision better.